# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null due to function

Tags: javascript, html

keep getting this error when trying to upload data, heres my js code:

```
displayOutput(data); //this is from ajax

function displayOutput(games)
{

    console.log(games[1]["Genres"]);
    let ul = document.getElementById('ajax');
    let output = "";

    games.forEach(game => {


            output+= "<a href=#><li>" + game["Name"]+"</a></li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Release Date"]+"</li>";         
            output+= "<li>" + game["Genres"]+"</li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Retail Price"]+"</li>";  
            output+= "<li>" + game["Rating"]+"</li>"; 
            output+= "<li>" + game["image"]+"</li>";    
            output += '<li><img src="${game.image}"></li>';
    })
    ul.innerHTML = output;
}
```

just want to note that when i add the first function, everything is fine

but when it comes to re-using the function. then it all goes crazy and ruins the original function. the original function is the first one, then re-using it is the 2nd block of code

Comment: Are you reusing the function or redefining it? Does it ruin the function of the output of the first function? Please explain what are you trying to do here.

Comment: alright so all its doing is displaying data from a json file. when i first typed out the function(first one) it worked fine. no issues. but when I re-used it(second function) it gave the first function an error.

Comment: Did you notice that the second function has `let ul = document.getElementById('ajaxCheck');` instead of `let ul = document.getElementById('ajax');` Does the HTML element with the id `ajaxCheck` exist?

Comment: it does, the 2nd function is targeting a different page id, thats why I changed it

Comment: OK, can you post the error you are seeing and where you are seeing it (a screenshot perhaps)? Also, can you post the full code? As far as I can see you are not reusing the function, you are redefining it - there is a difference and a huge one.

Comment: ive changed it to a forEach loop to make it clearer, how do I re-use it on another page with a different div?

Comment: You can just pass the element id as a parameter: `function displayOutput(games, elementId){}` and then use it inside the function: `document.getElementById(elementId)`.

Comment: but what if i want to alter something different but use the same code? like one page with a checkbox and another page without a checkbox

Comment: Look, you can define the second function - use a different name for it. Let me explain that in the official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to reuse the same function, and not redefine it. This would be the code:

```
displayOutput(data, id);

function displayOutput(games, elementID)
{
    console.log(games[1]["Genres"]);
    let ul = document.getElementById(elementID);
    let output = "";

    games.forEach(game => {
            output+= "<a href=#><li>" + game["Name"]+"</a></li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Release Date"]+"</li>";         
            output+= "<li>" + game["Genres"]+"</li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Retail Price"]+"</li>";  
            output+= "<li>" + game["Rating"]+"</li>"; 
            output+= "<li>" + game["image"]+"</li>";    
            output += '<li><img src="${game.image}"></li>';
    })
    ul.innerHTML = output;
}
```

If you want to have a variation by page in the function you can have some internal logic inside the function that recognizes which page is it, and then creates the appropriate output, or have a different function handling that. For example:

```
function displayOutput_userPage(games, elementID)
{
    console.log(games[1]["Genres"]);
    let ul = document.getElementById(elementID);
    let output = "";

    games.forEach(game => {
            output+= "<a href=#><li>" + game["Name"]+"</a></li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Release Date"]+"</li>";         
    })
    ul.innerHTML = output;
}
```

And for another page:

```
function displayOutput_shoppingCartPage(games, elementID)
{
    console.log(games[1]["Genres"]);
    let ul = document.getElementById(elementID);
    let output = "";

    games.forEach(game => {
            output+= "<a href=#><li>" + game["Name"]+"</a></li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Release Date"]+"</li>";         
            output+= "<li>" + game["Genres"]+"</li>";   
            output+= "<li>" + game["Retail Price"]+"</li>";  
            output+= "<li>" + game["Rating"]+"</li>"; 
            output+= "<li>" + game["image"]+"</li>";    
            output += '<li><img src="${game.image}"></li>';
    })
    ul.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, however If i do this, then for some reason I get the error: function.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at displayOutput (function.js:77)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleResponse